# Update component when input changes in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

```
     <div class=" card-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class=" font-icon-list col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-xs-6" routerLinkActive="active"
            *ngFor="let subject of subjects">
            <div class=" font-icon-detail">
              <div (click)="setSubject(subject.title)" >
                <i class="deep-icons  {{ subject.icon }}"></i>
                <p>{{ subject.title }}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     <subject-component [setSubjectService]="selectedSubject"></subject-component>
```

The code above is from my selector.component.html.

```
export class SubjectComponent implements OnInit {


@Input() public set setSubjectService(_subjectService: ISubjectService) {
    this.subjectService = _subjectService;
  }

  public subjectService: ISubjectService;

  constructor() {}

  public ngOnInit(): void {

  }
}
```

The code above is from my subject.component.ts

**Right now subject-component gets rendered once when the application starts up, but whenever "selectedSubject" changes it does not update or re-render. How can I make this possible?**

(Using Angular 8)

Comment: Are you using OnPush ChangeDetectionStrategy?

Comment: I've tried that this way: 
@Component({
  selector: ...
  templateUrl: ...
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

This is my subject.component.ts

Comment: And also having  "get runChangeDetection()" with a console.log in it. But it never prints.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use two way binding.
If so;
Create an output with eventemitter like;

```
@Input() myVariable: number;
@Output() myVariableChange = new EventEmitter(); //define it nameofyourvariable+Change

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {}

changeMyVar(v: number) {
   this.myVariable=v;
   this.myVariableChange.emit(myVariable);
}
```

And use two way binding with parantheses. I mean like following:

```
<subject-component [(setSubjectService)]="selectedSubject"></subject-component>
```

Comment: I think i get the idea and i've tried doing so, but the component isn't re-rendering.